# Deduplicate a table based on values in 2 columns + fuzzy matching

Tags: r, duplicates, record-linkage

I have a CSV file exported from [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) with metadata of my library entries. I know it contains quite a few duplicates, but it's not that easy to get rid of them:

- Not all items with similar titles are actually duplicates, e.g.

  ```
  | Year |            Author             |    Title     |
  +------+-------------------------------+--------------+
  | 2016 | Jones, Erik                   | Book Reviews |
  | 2016 | Hassner, Pierre; Jones, Erik  | Book Reviews |
  | 2010 | Adams, Laura L.; Gagnon, Chip | Book Reviews |
  ```
- Not all items that are actually similar have 100% identical metadata strings, e.g.

  ```
  |    Author     |                     Title                     |
  +---------------+-----------------------------------------------+
  | Tichý, Lukáš; | Can Iran Reduce EU Dependence on Russian Gas? |
  | Tichy, L.;    | "can iran reduce eu dependence onrussian gas" |
  ```

That is an extreme example (differences are not that big usually), but as you can see, pre-cleaning won't exactly solve this; so the idea is to eliminate rows that hold *similar* values in two+ columns - say, "Author" and "Title".

What I've tried/looked through so far:

- OpenRefine - barely familiar with it, so could not come up with or find anything viable.
- [Excel fuzzy lookup extension](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011) - does not really work the way I need.
- Python - again, I'm not good with the language; and I couldn't find any relevant solutions/guides.
- R: tried out a few ideas:

First use agrep in for loop on "Author" column to get indexes of rows with duplicates; then do the same for "Title" column; and then compare the vectors and dedupe the rows where values coincide. Needless to say, I couldn't move beyond step 1:

```
titles <- unlist(corpus$"Title")
for (i in 1:length(titles)){
  Title_dupe_temp <- agrep(titles[i], titles[i+1:length(titles)], 
                           max.distance = 1, ignore.case = TRUE, fixed = FALSE)
  Title_dupes[i] <- paste(i, Title_dupe_temp, sep = " ")
}
```

The result is (almost) complete gibberish; plus I get warning messages:

```
In Title_dupes[i] <- paste(i, Title_dupe_temp, sep = " ") :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I've also read through [fuzzywuzzyR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzywuzzyR/index.html) documentation, but did not find any functions that could help.

Finally, I've tried [RecordLinkage](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/index.html) package. Still, I could not go past the basics. [The documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/RecordLinkage.pdf) is rather heavy and not explicit on all things; guides are scarce, and the ones I've found (e.g. [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/vignettes/WeightBased.pdf)) use the example datasets which have identity vectors ready - and so I could not figure it out how to replicate that on my data.

So at this point I don't care whether to do it in OpenRefine/R/Py/SQL/whatever, just to do it in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution I:
using a loop and the library `stringdist`:

```
library(stringdist)
    zotero<-data.frame(
      Year=c(2016,2016,2010,2010,2010,2010),
      Author=c("Jones, Erik","Hassner, Pierre;","Adams, Laura L.;","Tichý, Lukáš;","Tichý, Lukáš;","Tichy, L.;"),
      Title=c("Book Reviews","Book Reviews","Book Reviews","Can Iran Reduce EU Dependence on Russian Gas?","Can Iran Reduce EU Dependence on Russian Gas?","can iran reduce eu dependence onrussian gas")
    )

    zotero$onestring<-paste0(zotero$Year,zotero$Author,zotero$Title)
    zotero<-zotero[order(zotero[,1],zotero[,2]),]

    atot<-NULL
    for (i in 2:dim(zotero)[1]){
      a<-stringdist(zotero$onestring[i-1],zotero$onestring[i])/(nchar(zotero$onestring[i-1])+nchar(zotero$onestring[i]))
      atot<-rbind(atot,a)
    }

    zotero<-cbind(zotero,threshold=c(1,atot))
    zotero[zotero$threshold>0.15,]
```

Solution II: it may be faster to compute that with a matrix than with a loop: First I create a dataframe based on your data sample, second I remove non-UTF characters, third I use the library `stringdist` to compute a distance matrix. You can easily convert these to percentages of similarity.

```
zotero<-data.frame(
  Year=c(2016,2016,2010,2010,2010,2010),
  Author=c("Jones, Erik","Hassner, Pierre;","Adams, Laura L.;","Tichý, Lukáš;","Tichý, Lukáš;","Tichy, L.;"),
  Title=c("Book Reviews","Book Reviews","Book Reviews","Can Iran Reduce EU Dependence on Russian Gas?","Can Iran Reduce EU Dependence on Russian Gas?","can iran reduce eu dependence onrussian gas")
)

zotero$onestring<-paste0(zotero$Year,zotero$Author,zotero$Title)

Encoding(zotero$onestring) <- "UTF-8"
zotero$onestring<-iconv(zotero$onestring, "UTF-8", "UTF-8",sub='')

library(stringdist)
stringdistmatrix(zotero$onestring)
```

Result:

```
> stringdistmatrix(zotero$onestring)
   1  2  3  4  5
2 11            
3 13 14         
4 47 45 44      
5 47 45 44  0   
6 47 45 42 13 13
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I fear though that this not an optimal solution for me; I have tens of thousands data rows, so it's  _automation/speed > precision_. And while it should be possible to do automatic merging based on `stringdist`, I still hope for a more straightforward way.

Comment: Btw, I found one of mistakes in my loop; been subsetting the vector in such a way that agrep always gave an indice of an element next to the one being matched; subsetting a char vector like `titles[-i]` (partially) fixes it, but is still too problematic in too many ways.

Comment: Ok, I added a solution with a loop, let me know what you think. I think stringdist is still the way to go. This is more straightforward than with a matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately, I'm too busy with other things to test it thoroughly right now, but I will in the next day or two (and will leave a comment of course).

Comment: I apologize it rook me song long to answer. So I would like to thank you again for the detailed example: it really does work really well and fast on larger datasets. Still, could you please explain why do you prefer to convert into percentages of similarity (it's what dividing the string distance by `(nchar(zotero$onestring[i-1])+nchar(zotero$onestring[i])` does, right?). It seems that using string distance directly is not that different; so is it just for convenience?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but I was thinking that shorter strings would then always have shorter character distances? Probably it's only an issue if your threshold is really high, so may simply delete this if it works for you without it.

Comment: It does make sense, and there was some difference in the number of deduped lines - though I thought it was because of the min threshold I set. I will check more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar approach to @Nakx, and I like the matrix solution. However, you could also try to clean up more using `gsub` and `iconv` and use sapply to do the matching (indexing the best match value that is not itself..0). Something like this:

```
    > library(RecordLinkage)
> 
> zotero<-data.frame(
+   Year=c(2016,2016,2010,2010,2010,2010),
+   Author=c("Jones, Erik","Hassner, Pierre;","Adams, Laura L.;","Tichý, Lukáš;","Tichý, Lukáš;","Tichy, L.;"),
+   Title=c("Book Reviews","Book Reviews","Book Reviews","Can Iran Reduce EU Dependence on Russian Gas?","Can Iran Reduce EU Dependence on Russian Gas?","can iran reduce eu dependence onrussian gas")
+ )
> 
> # Converting the special characters
> zotero$Author_new <- iconv(zotero$Author, from = '', to = "ASCII//TRANSLIT")
> zotero$Author_new <- tolower(zotero$Author_new)
> zotero$Author_new <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", zotero$Author_new)
> 
> # Removing punctuation making it lowercase
> zotero$Title_new <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", zotero$Title)
> zotero$Title_new <- tolower(zotero$Title_new)
> 
> # Removing exact duplicates
> dups <- duplicated(zotero[,c("Title_new", "Author_new", "Year")])
> zotero <- zotero[!dups,]
> zotero
  Year           Author                                         Title     Author_new
1 2016      Jones, Erik                                  Book Reviews     jones erik
2 2016 Hassner, Pierre;                                  Book Reviews hassner pierre
3 2010 Adams, Laura L.;                                  Book Reviews  adams laura l
4 2010    Tichý, Lukáš; Can Iran Reduce EU Dependence on Russian Gas?    tichy lukas
6 2010       Tichy, L.;   can iran reduce eu dependence onrussian gas        tichy l
                                     Title_new Title_dist Author_dist
1                                 book reviews          0           9
2                                 book reviews          0           9
3                                 book reviews          0           9
4 can iran reduce eu dependence on russian gas          0           0
6  can iran reduce eu dependence onrussian gas          1           4
>
> # Creating a distance measure for your title, author, and year
> zotero$Title_dist <- sapply(zotero$Title_new, function(x) sort(levenshteinDist(x, zotero$Title_new))[2])
> zotero$Author_dist <- sapply(zotero$Author_new, function(x) sort(levenshteinDist(x, zotero$Author_new))[2])
>
> # Filter here
```

And from there you can use the distance variables to create criteria and filter. E.g., you may feel comfortable removing if there is an author distance of 2 and a title distance of 5 for an article.

Edit to clarify an example of filtering. You'll need to adjust after looking at your data. Always good to start conservative

```
> library(dplyr)
> zotero <- zotero %>%
+   group_by(Year) %>%
+   filter(!between(Title_dist, 1, 5) | 
+          !between(Author_dist, 1, 5))
> zotero
# A tibble: 4 x 7
# Groups:   Year [2]
   Year Author       Title                     Author_new   Title_new                   Title_dist Author_dist
  <dbl> <fct>        <fct>                     <chr>        <chr>                            <int>       <int>
1  2016 Jones, Erik  Book Reviews              jones erik   book reviews                         0           9
2  2016 Hassner, Pi~ Book Reviews              hassner pie~ book reviews                         0           9
3  2010 Adams, Laur~ Book Reviews              adams laura~ book reviews                         0           9
4  2010 Tichý, Luká~ Can Iran Reduce EU Depen~ tichy lukas  can iran reduce eu depende~          0           0
```

Comment: Excuse me for the delayed response and thanks again! As for the preformatting - you're definitely right on this; it's something I always do when working with text data, just ommited this part in my post. As for the distance - `levenshteinDist` seems more heavyweight than `stringdist` (it took about 10 minutes to process titles in a ~4500-line tbl), but works fine. I also really like the idea of dealing with author and title fields separately.

Comment: Very true, this solution was definitely more for precision than speed--I just saw your first comment on the other solution. Also, if you are doing a meta-analysis, or some kind of systematic literature review, Zotero probably has a way to identify duplicates built-in to the software. I know that EndNote does. Best of luck!!!

Comment: Zotero has a built-in dedupe tool - it is quite handy and precise, but requires the user to do everything manually record by record, so wasn't a good solution in my case.